# Binomial Theorem implementation, including complex numbers

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

/*
 adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421835/c-binomial-coefficient-is-too-slow
*/
template<typename T = int, typename U = unsigned long long int>
inline U computeBinomialCoefficient(const T& n, const T& k) {
    if (n == k || k == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
   
    U out = n - k + 1;

    for (T i = 1; i < k; ++i) {
        out = out * (n - k + 1 + i) / (i + 1);
    }

    return out;
}

/*
 compute the horizontal shift of a polynomial
 with coefficients coeffs (decreasing order)
 by shift units
*/
template<typename T = int>
const std::vector<T> computeHorizontalShiftBinomialThm(const std::vector<T>& coeffs, const T& shift) {
    std::size_t size = coeffs.size();
    std::vector<T> out (size, 0);
   
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        T coefficient = coeffs[i];
        if (coefficient == 0) {
            continue;
        }
       
        std::size_t n = size - i - 1; // power of monomial
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            T kthPower = computeBinomialCoefficient(n, k) * powl(-1 * shift, n - k);
            out[size - k - 1] += coefficient * kthPower;
        }
    }
   
    return out;
}


/*
 Specialization for std::complex
*/
template<typename ComplexType>
const std::vector<std::complex<ComplexType>> computeHorizontalShiftBinomialThm(const std::vector<std::complex<ComplexType>>& coeffs, const std::complex<ComplexType>& shift) {
    using imag = std::complex<ComplexType>;
    
    std::size_t size = coeffs.size();
    std::vector<imag> out (size, 0);
   
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        imag coefficient = coeffs[i];
        if (coefficient == std::complex<ComplexType>(0, 0)) {
            continue;
        }
       
        std::size_t n = size - i - 1; // power of monomial
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            ComplexType binomialCoeff = computeBinomialCoefficient(n, k);
            imag power = (imag) pow(shift * (ComplexType) -1, n - k);
            imag kthPower = (std::complex<decltype(binomialCoeff)>) power * binomialCoeff;
            out[size - k - 1] += coefficient * kthPower;
        }
    }
   
    return out;
}



template<typename T>
void print(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (const T& n : vec) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intCoeffs {2, 19, 0, 0, 1};
    int intShift {5};

    auto intExample = computeHorizontalShiftBinomialThm(intCoeffs, intShift);
    print(intExample);
   
 
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> imaginaryCoeffs {1, 0, 0, 0};
    std::complex<double> imaginaryShift (0, 2);
   
    auto complexExample = computeHorizontalShiftBinomialThm(imaginaryCoeffs, imaginaryShift);
    print(complexExample);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And it works! I get out

```
2 -21 15 425 -1124 
(1,0) (3.67394e-16,-6) (-12,-1.46958e-15) (-1.46958e-15,8)
```

How can I reduce/eliminate floating point error, increase speed, and make the code easier to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid needing to specialize

It is possible to make just one template that can compute the desired result without having a specialization for `std::complex`. You just have to ensure that variables get their correct type. Some tricks you can use:

- Use `T{}` to get a default initialized value of type `T`; this is the way to get a correctly typed zero.
- Use `auto` where possible to let the compiler deduce the right type.
- Use operators or functions to get a result of the right type, for example:

  - Write `-foo` instead of `-1 * foo`.
  - Use `decltype(std::abs(value))` to get a scalar type even if `value` is `std::complex`.

Here is your template rewritten to work with `std::complex`:

```
template<typename T = int>
const std::vector<T> computeHorizontalShiftBinomialThm(const std::vector<T>& coeffs, const T& shift) {
    std::size_t size = coeffs.size();
    std::vector<T> out (size, 0);
   
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        T coefficient = coeffs[i];
        if (coefficient == T{}) {
            continue;
        }
       
        std::size_t n = size - i - 1;
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            T binomialCoeff = computeBinomialCoefficient(n, k);
            auto power = std::pow(-shift, n - k);
            auto kthPower = power * binomialCoeff;
            out[size - k - 1] += coefficient * kthPower;
        }
    }
   
    return out;
}
```

The only issue with the above code is that you want extended precision for some temporary variables like `binomialCoeff` and `power`. In particular you want to use `long long` if `T` is an integer type, `long double` if it's a floating point type, and `std::complex<long double>` if it's a complex number. To tackle this, I would create a separate template function to compute `kthPower`, and then this could be specialized for integers, floating point and complex types.

## Use `std::` versions of math functions

Use [`std::pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) instead of [`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow). The C++ versions of the math functions have overloads for the various floating point types, so you don't have to worry about whether you are passing in a `float`, `double`, `long double`. Even better, `std::pow()` has overloads where the first argument is a floating point number but the second is an integer, so it can choose a more optimal implementation for raising values to an integer power.

The same goes for all other function from `<cmath>`.

## Avoid unnecessary copies

You already pass the parameters by reference, which is great, especially if you pass containers or types of which you don't know the size. However, there are a few other places where copies could be made that might be expensive depending on the type.

The first is in the `for`-loop in `computeBinomialCoefficient()`. Use `out *= ...` instead of `out = out * ...`.

The other is `coefficient` in `computeHorizontalShiftBinomialThm()`. Use this instead:

```
const T& coefficient = coeffs[i];
```

For simple types like `float`, `double` and even `std::complex` types, the compiler will likely produce exactly the same code either way, but consider for example someone using a BigInt library and wanting to process very large numbers.

## Naming things

Your functions have very long names. Consider finding ways to make them more concise while still being clear and descriptive given the context they would be used in. I would drop the prefix `compute`; you won't see a `compute_sin()` function in the standard library for example.
Use `binomial()` instead of `computeBinomialCoefficient()`. I think it is usually clear that a function with that name that takes two parameters produces the binomial coefficient as the output. As for the function that does the horizontal shift, it might be a bit hard to come up with a better name apart from dropping the `compute` part.

Be consistent when naming things. I see both `coefficient` and the abbreviation `coeff` being used. Choose one and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion that I think is good is to cache the Ncr results.

```cpp
struct Ncr {
  using T = long double;
  static std::vector<T> &fact() {
    static std::vector<T> _fact{1};
    return _fact;
  }

  static std::vector<T> &inv_fact() {
    static std::vector<T> _inv_fact{1};
    return _inv_fact;
  }

  static T C(int n, int k) {
    if (k < 0 || k > n) {
      return 0;
    }
    while ((int) fact().size() < n + 1) {
      fact().push_back(fact().back() * (int) fact().size());
      inv_fact().push_back(1 / fact().back());
    }
    return fact()[n] * inv_fact()[k] * inv_fact()[n - k];
  }
};
```

I have added an example code and to use it you can directly call it by `Ncr::C(n, k)` this will save all the previous results and you might not have to recompute every time. You have to make sure you don't actually run this with `int` or any other small-sized DS as factorials encreases polynomially and can overflow in case of `int` or `long long`. That's why using `long double` might be helpful here.
Also, notice the `long double` this is actually to improve the precision. When I run the code I got the following output.

```
2 -21 15 425 -1124 
(1.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-6.000000) (-12.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,8.000000)
```